# How to fetch latest records first in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have list of records with following structure in my DynamoDB table:

```
{
 "id": "123rferfwefwef", 
 "date_created": "10-12-2018"
 "review_text": "Something", 
 "user": {
    "id": "fdjoiewjfew2", 
    "name": "Someone"
 }, 
 "teacher": {
    "id": "fewfwef232", 
    "name": "Someone"
 }, 
 "teacher_id": "fewfwefwefwef"
}
```

Here is my `params` to fetch data:

```
const params = {
    TableName: 'Reviews', 
    IndexName: 'teacher_id-index', 
    KeyConditionExpression: 'teacher_id = :id',
    ProjectionExpression: 'id, review_text, #user, date_created',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':id': teacher_id
    }, 
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#user': 'user'
    }
};
```

But why DynamoDB returns me data in some shuffled order, not sorted in "newest first" way? Of course, when I get records, I can sort them by `date_created` attribute. But it is not efficient. So, how to get records sorted in a such a way, when newest records appears first?

Comment: What is the hash/partition and range/sort key on the table?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it is not efficient"?

Comment: @cementblocks I have to indexes on my table here. In first index, the partition key is teacher_id. In second, user_id. There is no sort keys on my indexes. Also, no sort key on my table.

Comment: @SimrandeepSingh By telling this, I mean that AWS needs to handle this for developer. The question is can AWS do this itself?

Comment: Consider adding a sort key to the teacher_id index. Make it created date. Then when you query that index you can get the records sorted by the created date.

Comment: Are you talking about natural ordering ?